# Filter the values according to Date and Time

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Sample Data]I have been trying the below code to filter data in raw data sheet by using user inputed value in another sheet. Date is in one column and time is in another column. I need to filter the data using below example.

Start - 11/8/2022 00:30 End - 11/10/2022 14:00

I have tried the below code but its not working. output should we need to filter the data with start date as 11/08/2022 and in time column it should start from 00:30 till 23:30 and the next date 11/09/2022 and all the time intervals should be selected. and at last the date of 11/10/2022 should be selected and the time should be selected as 00:00 to 14:00.

11/08/2022 - 00:30-23:30
11/09/2022 - 00:00-23:30
11/10/2022 - 00:00:14:00

Please help me with this issue.

Thank you all for your support.

I have tried the below code modifying a little bit, but i couldnt able to do the required

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filter_My_Data()

Dim Data_sh As Worksheet
Dim Filter_Criteria_Sh As Worksheet
Dim Output_sh As Worksheet

Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set Filter_Criteria_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter_Criteria")
Set Output_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

Output_sh.UsedRange.Clear
Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim timelist() As long
Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Filter_Criteria_Sh.Range("A:A")) - 2

ReDim timelist(n) As long
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To n
    timelist(i) = Filter_Criteria_Sh.Range("A" & i + 2)
Next i

Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 3, timelist(), xlFilterValues
Data_sh.UsedRange.Copy Output_sh.Range("A1")
Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

MsgBox ("Data has been Copied")

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to use [AdvancedFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.advancedfilter)

Comment: I am afraid that the code you show has nothing to to with the question you try explaining in words. I think you should edit your question and better explain what you try doing. Besides filter criteria you should mention **what range do you intend filtering** and **how do you like setting the criteria as you tried explaining**? "Date is in one column and time is in another column" is not enough if you expect a concrete answer, I think.

Comment: Above code shows that it only filters time between two times. but i need to include the dates as well as i mentioned above

Comment: Your above code filters using an array extracted from A:A column. It does not use any start - end pair of dates. With or without time...

Answer (score 0):

The advanced filter can get pretty deep.  Ref:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-advanced-filter/

[image]

Fill in all but the OUTPUT.  Then run the demo which will make the filter.

This may get you going.  In a Module, these functions return TRUE/FALSE from comparing the dates and times to those in B12:B15

```
Function GE_Date1(zcell As Range) As Boolean ' compares to date in B12
  GE_Date1 = (zcell.Value >= Range("B12").Value)
End Function

Function GE_Time1(zcell As Range) As Boolean ' compares to time in B13
  GE_Time1 = (zcell.Value >= Range("B13").Value)
End Function

Function LE_Date2(zcell As Range) As Boolean ' compares to date in B14
  LE_Date2 = (zcell.Value <= Range("B14").Value)
End Function

Function LE_Time2(zcell As Range) As Boolean ' compares to time in B15
  LE_Time2 = (zcell.Value <= Range("B15").Value)
End Function
```

This can be in your sheet to do the filter.
The first 2 lines fill in A2:D2 - this would be done on the sheet, not VBA.

```
Sub FilterDemo()
  ' -- fill in the criteria
  Range("A2", "B2") = Array("=GE_Date1(A4)", "=GE_Time1(B4)")
  Range("C2", "D2") = Array("=LE_Date2(A4)", "=LE_Time2(B4)")
  ' -- now do the filtering.  the most help is
  ' https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-advanced-filter/
  ' "Formulas in the Advanced Filter criteria"
  Range("A3:C10").AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, _
    Range("A1:D2"), Range("F3"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

EDIT: Some clarification:
A1:D1 - Criteria heading cells - "should be blank, or be different from any of the list range headings."  What I have is the formulas that are entered in A2:D2.  To enter the texts, you have to precede them with a ' (quote).
A2:D2 - These are the criteria; they are formulas (functions) returning TRUE/FALSE; GE = Greater than or Equal to; LE = Less than or Equal to. Formulas don't show (the values show) so I made them "xx" and entered the formulas in the VBA script.
B12:B15 - Entered as Dates and Times
From the link:
"Criteria on the same row are joined with an AND operator."
"Criteria on different rows are joined with an OR operator."
So all 4 formulas are ANDed together (all 4 must be TRUE).